# How to Compose a certain part in MEF?

Tags: c#, mef

I have an MEF extension and a class library that composes parts of it.
Currently how I see it works is like following

```
_container.ComposeParts(obj);
```

The above will compose all attributed parts inside the members of the class of obj. I would like to do something like the following (Note: The following code is for demonstrative purposeS only and does not relate to CompositionContainer object model as documented in MSDN)

```
IMyCustomPart partObj = _container.ComposeACertainPart<IMyCustomPart>();
```

Does MEF allows that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `GetExportXXXXX` methods of [CompositionContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.compositioncontainer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

To get a single part:

```
var part = _container.GetExportedValue<IMyCustomPart>();
```

Note that this will work only if there is exactly one exported part.

To a sequence of exported parts (zero or more):

```
var parts = _container.GetExportedValues<IMyCustomPart>();
```

This is preferred if you want to avoid thrown [ImportCardinalityMismatchException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.importcardinalitymismatchexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

MEF also supports lazy exports (Lazy<>). These can be very handy if you want parts to be created in a lazy fashion.

Note however that by default MEF is exporting shared parts. Meaning that only one instance is created and passed around during composition or call to GetExportXXXX. To overcome this you can set a non-shared [PartCreationPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.partcreationpolicyattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
[Export]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy = CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class MyExportedClass { ... }
```

Finally there is [ExportFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff382807%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which can help if you want to create non-shared parts and handle their lifetime yourself (which in most other case is done by the container). For an intro on ExportFactory have a look at [ExportFactory in MEF 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2011/11/17/exportfactory-amp-lt-t-amp-gt-in-mef-2-alok.aspx?Redirected=true).

Answer (score 1):

How about using [MEF ExportFactory](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PartCreator)?

You can do this then:

```
[Export]
public class YourClass {

  [Import] 
  public ExportFactory<MyCustomPart> CustomPartExporter {get; set;}

  public IMyCustomPart GetMyCustomPart() {
    return CustomPartExporter.CreateExport().Value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your type has a constructor that you can use the `ComposeExportedValue` method with the `GetExport<T>` method.  For example:

```
IMyCustomPart partObj = _container.ComposeExportedValue( _container.GetExport<IMyCustomPart>().Value );
```

Disclaimer: I have not had a chance to test this.